# Colocar data de 5 dias adiantado

Tags: javascript, data

Tipo, se hoje é dia 14 de julho aparece dia 19 de julho e se fosse 30 de julho aparece 4 de agosto.

```js
teste = new Array ("janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro")
TESTE = new Date


document.write ("Válido até dia " + TESTE.getDate () + " de " + teste [TESTE.getMonth() ]   +  ", corra e garanta sua vaga!")
```

Como fazer pra mudar? (sei que se a data da pessoa tiver errada não vai dar certo)

Comment: `TESTE.setDate(TESTE.getDate() + 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só isto que deseja?

```js
let meses = ["janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro"];
let data = new Date();
data.setDate(data.getDate() + 5);
document.write("Válido até dia " + data.getDate() + " de " + meses[data.getMonth()] + ", corra e garanta sua vaga!<br>");
data = new Date(2019, 6, 30);
data.setDate(data.getDate() + 5);
document.write("Válido até dia " + data.getDate() + " de " + meses[data.getMonth()] + ", corra e garanta sua vaga!");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/AddDays.js).

Só somei 5 nos dias, e melhorei o código de forma geral.